# Application of mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

$f$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$, and satisfies $f(a)<f(b)$, $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$.
Show that there exists $c$ in $[a,b]$

\begin{equation}
\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}=f'(c)
\end{equation}

How is the mean value theorem 
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)
\end{equation}
applicable here?

Comment: This is Flett's Mean Value Theorem. Mean Value Theorem is applied in the proof in the form of Rolle's Theorem. This link may help: www.math.sc.edu/~girardi/m555/current/hw/MVT-Flett.pdf

Comment: Your question appears to be simply a special case of the mean value theorem. Am I missing something? Where are you stuck? (Argh sorry I read the $c$'s as $b$'s in the first equation)

Comment: @Hugh the mean value theorem applies for $c$ in $(a,b)$

Comment: Thanks user71352 for the link to Flett MVT.

Comment: @use71352 Thank you very much for posting the link that is very helpful.

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad to hear it was helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the auxiliary function
$$g(x):={f(x)-f(a)\over x-a} \quad(a<x\leq b), \quad g(a):=0\ .$$
Then $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$. One computes
$$g'(x)={(x-a) f'(x)-\bigl(f(x)-f(a)\bigr)\over (x-a)^2}\qquad(0<x\leq b)\ .$$
If $g(b)=0$, then this is a consequence of Rolle's Theorem.

If $g(b)>0$, then $g'(b)<0$; therefore $g(x)>g(b)>0$ immediately to the left of $b$. This allows us to conclude that $g$ assumes its maximum on $[0,b]$ in an interior point $c$. From $g'(c)=0$ it then follows that
$${f(c)-f(a)\over c-a}=f'(c)\ .$$

The case for $g(b)<0$ is similar.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Blatter, for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, this is Flett's version of the MVT.  A proof of this can be found at [this link](http://www.math.sc.edu/~girardi/m555/current/hw/MVT-Flett.pdf), also from  the comments.

Comment: In regards to the link, what is Flett reverencing when he says "then there exists an $x_1$ in $a<x_1<b$ such that $\phi(x_1)>\phi(b)$"?